# problem when using PowerBI Embed, in Incoporação what can be

Tags: azure, powerbi

returns me an error message and I have access to the created application.

"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'saddsa445das54sa4a-4asd4sda4-45asd4asd5' named 'Application'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: 495c6052-6df9-4533-9ef4-c0a007932e00\r\nCorrelation ID: 79e579fc-c2da-458c-bcf2-fb89a5831bb6\r\nTimestamp: 2020-02-05 14:28:14Z"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are authenticating and acquiring access token in a non-interactive way (i.e. with username and password, or application id and secret) and because of that you can't get a prompt for consent. Either temporarily change the way you are acquiring the token to be interactive (i.e. to be prompted for credentials), or go to [Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/register-app#using-the-azure-ad-portal), find your app in Azure AD and in API permissions for Power BI service select `Grant Consent`:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help, and I managed to solve the problem, put as permissions of the Service and apparently everything works, but this message occurs, you have to grant or access the service to the administrator.